# Using CString object in CString::Format

Tags: c++, mfc

Can I use `CString` in `CString::Format` as follows:

```
CString text = _T("text");
CString format;
format.Format(_T("%s"), text);
```

The same method is seen in MFC source files and MFC books. For example:

```
//From MFC file:
//C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\
//    afxeditbrowsectrl.cpp
BOOL CMFCEditBrowseCtrl::OnIllegalFileName(CString& strFileName)
{
    CString strError;
    CString strMessage;
    ...
    strMessage.Format(_T("%Ts\r\n%Ts"), strFileName, strError);
    //I don't know what is the `T` in `"%Ts"` !
    ...
}
```

Yet, other MFC source files use `LPCTSTR` cast. Example:

```
format.Format(_T("%s"), (LPCTSTR)text);
```

Is the cast mandatory?

Comment: If you want to be able to use any other compiler than the Visual C++ compiler, then yes it's mandatory. It works with Visual C++ because of how the compiler handles objects and their first member variable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: MFC is part of Visual Studio, and only compatible with its compiler. Compiling MFC code with any other compiler is not a supported scenario. But even if you do, the object layout is guaranteed to be the same across all implementations. That's an implementation detail of the `CString` implementation, though, and not officially documented. Either the cast, or calling the `GetString()` member are mandatory.

Comment: Just searched here for GetString() compatible version in VS6. Found here the (LPCTSTR) operator that we can use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentation of the `CStringT` class template:

> You can freely substitute `CStringT` objects for `PCXSTR` function arguments.

Whenever a function parameter expects a constant C-style string, you can pass a `CStringT` object, that is implicitly converted by invoking the [operator PCXSTR()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#operator_pcxstr).

A function with [variadic arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments), on the other hand, takes an untyped list of arguments. In this scenario, passing a `CStringT` object where a `PCXSTR` is (semantically) expected, is not safe. The compiler has no means of knowing, that it should emit code to perform the implicit conversion. You are responsible for performing the conversion yourself, either by invoking `operator PCXSTR()`, or by calling the [GetString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getstring) class member.

This is as far as the documented contract goes. To understand why it is still (technically) safe to pass a `CStringT` through a variadic argument list, it helps to take a look at the implementation<sup>1</sup>:

The [CSimpleStringT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class) class template is the base for all supported string classes. It contains a single (private) data member of type `PCXSTR`, and no virtual functions, making it a [standard layout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout) type. The binary representation is thus identical to that of its only member, a pointer to a zero-terminated array of characters.

---

Unrelated to the discussion of this Q&A, yet for completeness' sake, here is a brief explanation, of how the `CSimpleStringT` keeps track of the additional data (like string length or reference count). The only data member `m_pszData` points into a structure of type [CStringData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringdata-class), that consists of an initial sequence of constant size, storing the bookkeeping information, immediately followed by an array of characters of length `nAllocLength + 1`. `m_pszData` points at this array, and the additional data is retrieved through pointer arithmetic, as implemented by the private `GetData()` member:

```
CStringData* GetData() const throw()
{
    return( reinterpret_cast< CStringData* >( m_pszData )-1 );
}
```

The class layout is summarized in the following diagram:

```
                        +------------------------+
                        | CStringData            |
                        +========================+
                        | pStringMgr             |
+----------------+      | nDataLength            |
| CSimpleStringT |      | nAllocLength           |
+================+      | nRefs                  |
| m_pszData      | ---> | data[0]                |
+----------------+      | data[1]                |
                        . ...                    .
                        | data[nAllocLength - 1] |
                        | data[nAllocLength]     |
                        +------------------------+
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *This is based on the implementation that ships with Visual Studio 2017, that can - in theory - change without prior notice.*

Comment: "or by calling the GetString() class member." - I have replaced `variable` (CString) by `variable.GetString()` in my code, but the compiler still gives warning C6284 for the `Format()` call.

Comment: No, sorry, it's just that the Visual Studio error list window did not update... I had to run the code analysis again.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use the cast, you're passing the CString object by value.  That just happens to work because of the way CString is implemented, and there is no guarantee that the CString implementation will never change.