# Is it safe to replace LPCTSTR with CString?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, desktop-application, c-strings

A parameter of function requires an `LPCTSTR` type variable; what if we pass a `CString` type variable? Is it safe or is there anything that we should look at in this case?

For example this function :

```
Add(new CAToolbar, _T("Command Toolbar"), xtpBarTop);
```

Here I want to replace `_T("Command Toolbar")` (`LPCTSTR` type) with `CString str;`. Something like this:

```
Add(new CAToolbar, str , xtpBarTop);
```

Is it safe ?

Comment: You will probably have to show an example of where you  and how want to replace.

Comment: If it helps `LPCTSTR` is an alias for `const char*` or `const wchar_t*` depending on the unicode setting.

Comment: @devguy edit your post to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 8):

> *Is it safe or is there anything that we should look at in this case?*

*Generally* (see note, below), yes, it is safe. The `CString` class has an `operator LPCTSTR()`, which returns the content of the string as a C-style, nul-terminated `char` or `wchar_t` array (well, a pointer to its first element), depending on the current compiler setting of the "Character Set" option (i.e. whether or not `UNICODE` and/or `_UNICODE` is/are defined). Thus, the returned type will (or *should*) match the required `const char*` *vs* `const wchar_t*` pointer type for your function parameter. (Note that this is *not* safe to use for function parameters that are *not* `const` qualified).

In "olden days", there were some compilers that I used that would complain about the 'implicit' conversion when doing just this, so I used the `CString::GetString()` function, instead. However, these do **exactly** the same thing. From the "atlsimpstr.h" header:

```cpp
template< typename BaseType , bool t_bMFCDLL = false>
class CSimpleStringT
{
//...
    operator PCXSTR() const throw()
    {
        return( m_pszData );
    }
//...
    PCXSTR GetString() const throw()
    {
        return( m_pszData );
    }
//...
```

---

**Important Note:** One case where using this "implicit conversion" is **not** safe is for functions that take [variadic arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments), like `printf` or the `.Format()` member of `CString` itself; in such cases, the compiler will (rightly) complain of non-portable use of a class object. Take the following code:

```cpp
#include <afx.h>

int main()
{
    CString param = _T("param");
    CString text;
    text.Format(_T("Param is %s"), param);

    return 0;
}
```

The clang-cl compiler gives this error:

> error : cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'CString' (aka
> 'CStringT<wchar_t, StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t>>') through variadic
> method; call will abort at runtime [-Wnon-pod-varargs]

And even MSVC itself gives:

> warning C4840: non-portable use of class
> 'ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>'
> as an argument to a variadic function

In such a case, you can either use the `.GetString()` function mentioned earlier, or make the conversion *explicit*:

```cpp
    text.Format(_T("Param is %s"), param.operator LPCTSTR());
// or ...
    text.Format(_T("Param is %s"), static_cast<LPCTSTR>(param));
```

Comment: Nitpicking: *"the compiler will (rightly) complain of non-portable conversions"* - It's actually complaining about *"non-portable **use**"*. Variadic arguments have no associated type information, and there is no attempt to convert to an (unknown) destination type. This is different from, say, [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) sporting parameter packs (with type information). Here, arguments can be implicitly converted, and integrity is verified at compile time or run time.

Comment: As an aside: Passing a `CStringT` instance as the argument for a `%s` placeholder does indeed work as desired. This is a consequence of the class layout which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48250226/1889329). This is more of a party trick, and certainly not recommended. Even Microsoft now explicitly [mandate an explicit type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/cstring-operations-relating-to-c-style-strings#_core_using_cstring_objects_with_variable_argument_functions) when passing `CStringT` instances to functions with variadic arguments.

Comment: I never thought of the variadic parameter case either.  But rather than making a call to `param.operator LPCTSTR()` I'd use `static_cast<LPCTSTR>(param)`.

Comment: Never let the ease of writing outweigh the ease of reading.  To be honest all the C++-style casts are kind of a pain, but their meaning is crystal clear.

Answer (score 3):

`CString` contains an implicit conversion operator for `LPCTSTR`. It was designed for this exact usage.

It's the fact that you're passing a `const` string that can't be modified that makes it safe.